# Group By with Case statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need find the <strike>number</strike> Sum of orders over a 3 day range. so imagine a table like this

**Order**      **Date**
300     1/5/2015
200     1/6/2015
150     1/7/2015
250     1/5/2015
400     1/4/2015
350     1/3/2015
50        1/2/2015
100     1/8/2015

So I want to create a Group by Clause that Groups anything with a date that has the same Month, Year and a Day from 1-3 or 4-6, 7-9 and so on until I reach 30 days.

It seems like what I would want to do is create a case for the grouping that includes a loop of some type but I am not sure if this is the best way or if it is even possible to combine them.

An alternative might be create a case statement that creates a new column that assigns group number and then grouping by that number, month, and Year.

Unfortunately I've never used a case statement so I am not sure which method is best or how to execute them especially with a loop.

EDIT: I am using Access so it looks like I will be using **IIF** instead of Case

Comment: Are you actually using access? Access does not have a case statement. It has IIF though

Comment: It would be ideal if Access had analytic functions, but it does not. That being said, it doesn't look like you actually want orders over a 3 day range? That would be a count of orders, on each row, for the date on that row, and the 2 days prior (on a rolling basis, with overlap). You don't want overlap is that right? So day 1 to 3 would be a group? And day 4 would be the start of a new group (not including days 3 and 2)?

Comment: Yeah I don't want overlap and day 4 would be the start of a new group. I'd create some conditional statement for the 31st day of the month to just be included in the last group.

Comment: Would you be running this one month at a time?

Comment: No I wont why do you want ask.

Comment: Just wondering, the query can be written different ways which might look better or worse depending on what timeframe you're looking at. In my answer below you'll have one row per month, with each column showing a count of orders in days 1-3, 4-6, etc. That may be ideal if you're looking at a long period of time, but you might not want the pivoted counts if you're looking at just one month.

Comment: Your comments seem to indicate that you want to sum the orders column, but your question indicates you want the "number of orders" (which would indicate you're interested in a count). You may want to update your question if you want the sum of order quantity over a 3 day range. I thought that the order column was an order # column, not an order quantity column, when I first read this.

Comment: I am sorry this is my mistake!

Comment: No problem just wanted to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the [Partition Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/partition-function-HA001228892.aspx) and a crosstab, so, for example:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Calendar.Order) AS SumOfOrder
SELECT Month([CalDate]) AS TheMonth, Partition(Day([Caldate]),1,31,3) AS DayGroup
FROM Calendar
GROUP BY Month([CalDate]), Partition(Day([Caldate]),1,31,3)
PIVOT Year([CalDate]);
```

As an aside, I hope you have not named a field / column as Date.

Comment: Works great, that partition function is perfect though I am not sure why I need the Pivot.

Comment: I thought a crosstab was prettier :) You do not have to have it, but it does group nicely!

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

**COUNT OF ORDERS**

```
select      year([Date]) as yr,
            month([Date]) as monthofyr,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=1) and (day([Date])<=3),1,0)) as days1to3,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=4) and (day([Date])<=6),1,0)) as days4to6,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=7) and (day([Date])<=9),1,0)) as days7to9,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=10) and (day([Date])<=12),1,0)) as days10to12,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=13) and (day([Date])<=15),1,0)) as days13to15,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=16) and (day([Date])<=18),1,0)) as days16to18,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=19) and (day([Date])<=21),1,0)) as days19to21,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=22) and (day([Date])<=24),1,0)) as days22to24,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=25) and (day([Date])<=27),1,0)) as days25to27,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=28) and (day([Date])<=31),1,0)) as days28to31
from        tbl
where       [Date] between x and y
group by    year([Date]),
            month([Date])
```

Replace x and y with your date range.

The last group is days 28 to 31 of the month, so it may contain 4 days' worth of orders, for months that have 31 days.

THE ABOVE IS A COUNT OF ORDERS.

If you want the SUM of the order amounts:

**SUM OF ORDER AMOUNTS**

```
select      year([Date]) as yr,
            month([Date]) as monthofyr,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=1) and (day([Date])<=3),order,0)) as days1to3,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=4) and (day([Date])<=6),order,0)) as days4to6,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=7) and (day([Date])<=9),order,0)) as days7to9,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=10) and (day([Date])<=12),order,0)) as days10to12,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=13) and (day([Date])<=15),order,0)) as days13to15,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=16) and (day([Date])<=18),order,0)) as days16to18,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=19) and (day([Date])<=21),order,0)) as days19to21,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=22) and (day([Date])<=24),order,0)) as days22to24,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=25) and (day([Date])<=27),order,0)) as days25to27,
            sum(iif((day([Date])>=28) and (day([Date])<=31),order,0)) as days28to31
from        tbl
where       [Date] between x and y
group by    year([Date]),
            month([Date])
```

Comment: what am I summing? I am trying to sum the orders column.

Comment: It's not summing the column itself, it is a conditional count (notice the 1 or 0 at the end)

Comment: If the order is between day 1 and 3, for instance, it will add 1, otherwise it will add 0. The total is a conditional count for each of your groups.

Comment: You did want a count right? If you want to sum the order number itself, you would replace each 1 in the function with "order". Is that the case? If so I'll update the answer.

Comment: I am sorry I wanted a sum of the Orders not the number of, this is my mistake.